# Chapter title placement

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters

How can I delete the white space between the chapter's title and the beginning of the page? That is, how to place a chapter's title the higher possible?  I am using the `book` class.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to answer this question, it's helpful to know what document class you're using.  a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be even better.

Answer (score 3):

For the `book` class, you could redefine the `\@makechapterhead`. Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
text

\newpage

text

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}% in the original 50\p@, 
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\chapter{Second}
text

\end{document}
```

With

```
\makeatletter
\show\@makechapterhead
\makeatother
```

before redefining `\@makechapterhead` you can tell LaTeX to show you the current definition of `\@makechapterhead`. If `-\baselineskip` still is not enough, you could sum up the lengths `\headheight`, `\headsep`, `\baselineskip` and whatever you want and use the negative of this length for the `\vspace*{...}`. (Some fixed value like `3cm` would be possible, of course, but when you change font size, page size or something else this would need to be changed, too.)

Comment: Forgot to mention. I am using the {book} class. I am using the command  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt} in combination with the \titleformat, by calling the {titlesec} package. The result is a little improvement, but there is still some space. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @John: The answer is now given for the `book` class. Does that help?

Comment: @John: Good to read this. You can also [accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852), which also adds reputation for you and the person giving the answer, which would be me in this case :-)